# run a function before the garbage collector removes a class

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty sure i already know the answer but ill ask anyway, so i want to run a function when the GC removes a class instance my use case is, i created a wrapper class around `document.createElement` which gives me easy controls over the newly created element and i want to remove the element from the DOM as soon as the class instance gets deleted, i know i can just create a remove function which i already have but automating it would be nice.

Pseudo Code

```
class BaseElement {
  element = document.createElement('div')
  constructor() {
    document.body.appendChild(this.element)
  }
  // if its possible then im sure that its not this easy and would
  // involve changing some prototype prop or something like that.
  // this is just something to pass the annoying qualty filter.
  beforGC() {
    this.element.remove()
  }

}
```

Comment: Doubt there is anything like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you seem to suspect, no, JavaScript doesn't provide any kind of "finalizer" (a function that gets run before an object is GC'd).

Your best bet is indeed to have whatever is releasing the object also tell it to clean up.

Comment: I guess you could wrap the functionality in a small module, so you'd call something like `myModule.remove(someObj)` which will run `someObj.beforeGC` and then drop the reference to the object to be garbage collected.

Comment: @VLAZ - No need for the complexity, it's not uncommon to have a `destroy` method or similar that does this sort of thing, directly on the object.

Comment: My point is that if you are going to do this from multiple places, you may as well wrap the `obj.destroy(); storage.remove(obj);` (or equivalent) into a single function, so you do this centrally.